# Webpack url-loader jpg file inline

Tags: javascript, webpack, urlloader

I am trying to inline loading a jpg using url-loader like this:

```
let image1 = require("url?limit=100000000!./samples/sample.jpg");
```

after running I get:

```
"data:image/jpeg;base64,bW9kdWxlLmV4cG9ydHMgPSBfX3dlYnBhY2tfcHVibGljX3BhdGhfXyArICIuL3d3d3cvaW1nL3NhbXBsZS5qcGciOw=="
```

The base 64 string decodes as:

```
module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ + "./wwww/img/sample.jpg";
```

I was expecting the base64 string of the binary file.

Is this expected behaviour? how can I actually achieve the base64 string of the binary file?

If I try to inline say an html file it works as expected..so why not with jpgs?

Filesize of this particular file is 417 KB but the limit parameter is way bigger than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't try it, but something like this should work:

> let image1 = require("!!url?limit=100000000!./samples/sample.jpg");

The problem is the loader order. If you check your `webpack.config` files, somewhere you have the `file-loader` there for `jpg` files. I know that because I know `file-loader` would output this:

```
module.exports = \__webpack_public_path__ + "./wwww/img/sample.jpg";
```

... which is being piped into `url-loader`. That's why you're getting the base64 version of the string above. Because `file-loader` is returning that to the `url-loader`.

Please refer to the [loader order documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html#loader-order) to learn how to override it. I think putting !! before will solve your problem.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks I was not aware of the loader order and piping. Thanks for that